# LEAK with WebkitGTK

Tags: javascript, c, webkit, webkitgtk

I'm experimenting with WebkitGTK.  Using a simple "hello world" style app that does nothing but download a webpage and then quit, WebKit reports leaked objects after running the program:

```
LEAK: 1 CachedResource
LEAK: 12 WebCoreNode
```

The WebkitGTK program is a simple C program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void load_status_callback(GObject* object, GParamSpec* pspec, void* window)
{
        WebKitWebView* view = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(object);
        WebKitLoadStatus status = webkit_web_view_get_load_status(view);

        switch (status) 
        {
            case WEBKIT_LOAD_FINISHED:
            {
                printf("WEBKIT_LOAD_FINISHED\n");
                gtk_main_quit();
                break;
            }
            default: g_assert_not_reached();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);
    WebKitWebView *webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());

    GtkWidget *scrolledWindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolledWindow),
    GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledWindow), GTK_WIDGET(webView));
    g_signal_connect(webView, "notify::load-status", G_CALLBACK(load_status_callback), main_window);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_window), scrolledWindow);

    webkit_web_view_load_uri(webView, "http://127.0.0.1/test.html");
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(webView));
    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);

    gtk_main(); // Run main event loop

    gtk_widget_destroy(main_window);

    return 0;
}
```

The HTML I download is simply:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After some experimentation, I observe that the leak DOESN'T occur if I remove the `<script>` tag, which makes me believe that I'm supposed to do something to shut down JavaScriptCore.  So, why is WebKit reporting leaks?

Answer (score 1):

This is not anything you've done wrong in your code. Your problem is that you're using a debug build of WebKit, and so it's reporting WebKit bugs: memory leaks that ought to be fixed inside of WebKit.

You should switch to using a release build of WebKit, unless you're actually trying to debug something specific. Debug builds are slower, and run with assertions enabled, which is practice makes them crash dramatically more often than release builds.